# Xen ARM - How to transfer pages between domains by using grant table

Tags: memory-management, arm, xen, hypervisor, armv8

So far, I can run **Xen v4.9** on **ARMv8** and have Dom0 and DomU run normally. 

Next, I want to transfer pages (change page ownership) from one domain to another by using grant table.

But I always got `bad page` status while issuing hypercall to transfer the page.
I looked into the implementation of `gnttab_transfer` in `xen/common/grant_table.c`

I found that it will call `steal_page()` implemented in `xen/arch/arm/mm.c`

```
if ( steal_page(d, page, 0) < 0 )
{
    put_gfn(d, gop.mfn);
    gop.status = GNTST_bad_page;
    goto copyback;
}
```

In Xen v4.9, it simply returns -1.

```
int steal_page(struct domain *d, struct page_info *page, unsigned int memflags)
{
    return -1;
}
```

While in Xen v4.11 (the latest version), the operation is not supported.

```
int steal_page(struct domain *d, struct page_info *page, unsigned int memflags)
{
    return -EOPNOTSUPP;
}
```

I don't know the reason why it didn't support, and I made some guess:

1. The architecture of ARM didn't support memory transfer? But why?
2. ARM has other efficient method to transfer memory page? Which one?
3. The function is still under construction? Seems not...

If DomU wants to access Disk, it must operate with Dom0.

The data read from Disk may be huge such as video, image, and etc.

So it must transfer the page (change page ownership) instead of mapping and copying.

**How can I transfer the page?

Why don't Xen ARM support?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is some patch regarding implementation steal_page() on ARM

```
int steal_page(
    struct domain *d, struct page_info *page, unsigned int memflags)
{
    unsigned long x, y;
    bool_t drop_dom_ref = 0;
    const struct domain *owner = dom_xen;

    spin_lock(&d->page_alloc_lock);

    if ( is_xen_heap_page(page) || ((owner = page_get_owner(page)) != d) )
        goto fail;

    /*
     * We require there is just one reference (PGC_allocated). We temporarily
     * drop this reference now so that we can safely swizzle the owner.
     */
    y = page->count_info;
    do {
        x = y;
        if ( (x & (PGC_count_mask|PGC_allocated)) != (1 | PGC_allocated) )
            goto fail;
        y = cmpxchg(&page->count_info, x, x & ~PGC_count_mask);
    } while ( y != x );

    /* Swizzle the owner then reinstate the PGC_allocated reference. */
    page_set_owner(page, NULL);
    y = page->count_info;
    do {
        x = y;
        BUG_ON((x & (PGC_count_mask|PGC_allocated)) != PGC_allocated);
    } while ( (y = cmpxchg(&page->count_info, x, x | 1)) != x );

    /* Unlink from original owner. */
    if ( !(memflags & MEMF_no_refcount) && !domain_adjust_tot_pages(d, -1) )
        drop_dom_ref = 1;
    page_list_del(page, &d->page_list);

    spin_unlock(&d->page_alloc_lock);
    if ( unlikely(drop_dom_ref) )
        put_domain(d);
    return 0;

 fail:
    spin_unlock(&d->page_alloc_lock);
    gdprintk(XENLOG_WARNING,
             "Bad page %lx: ed=%d sd=%d caf=%08lx taf=%" PRtype_info,
             page_to_mfn(page), d->domain_id,
             owner ? owner->domain_id : DOMID_INVALID,
             page->count_info, page->u.inuse.type_info);
    return -1;
}
```

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/7874301/

And also, some interesting mail lists:

> Currently XENMEM_exchange is not supported on ARM because the
>   steal_page is  left unimplemented.
>
> However, even if steal_page is implemented, the hypercall can't work
>   for ARM  because:
>
> - Direct mapped domain is not supported
> - ARM doesn't have a M2P and therefore usage of mfn_to_gmfn is  invalid

from this https://lists.gt.net/xen/devel/411530

Hope I spread some light on your question.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I use the patch and then it works. I have seen the mail list before. Are XENMEM_exchange and Grant Table Transfer different cases? Why can't ARM support XENMEM_exchange due to "Direct mapped domain is not supported", but can support Grant Table Transfer